# How do I join an azure vm to onprem domain through extension?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, virtual-machine

I've got a problem using extensions to join a server to domain. I'm not sure what went wrong with this and could use the help.

Here's the issue:

I have a powershell script that's fairly standard at the core across the web that when I login to the new server and run it, will join my computer to a domain.

```
param(
 $p = 'password'
)

#create a credential
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $p –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList 'domain\serviceaccount', $SecurePassword

# add to domain
Add-Computer -DomainName domain.com -Credential $Credential
```

I create a powershell file out of it, saved it to blob storage, and wrote a script that will set a bunch of scripts as an extension, then download this among other files to the machine for initial processing. Once downloaded I get an error that I can't seem to track down over the web. I located this error by browsing the portal to the machine then looking at the status of the extension itself:

*"message": "ConvertTo-SecureString : The parameter value "String  'AsPlainText" is not a valid encrypted string....[ConvertTo-SecureString], PSArgumentException\  + FullyQualifiedErrorId ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand  New-Object : Cannot find type [TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ArgumentList]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded."*

Is there a proper way to handle this?

I've tried:

1. Removing the parameter entirely and having it just be a variable with the assignment
2. removing the above variable and just providing the password into the **-String** field.
3. Permutations of the above using single quotes vs no quotes.

Everything results in an invalid string, leaving me to believe that this is just one of those things I shouldn't be attempting.

I've seen some extensions and stuff on github but those only seem to work for Azure AD. I'm specifically joining to an AD forest that we have onprem that's replicated to the cloud, and don't believe in using those.

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be 2 errors

First

> The parameter value "String 'AsPlainText" is not a valid encrypted
>   string

It appears that the $p and the "-" before String and AsPlainText have been escaped. It therefore thinks that the first parameter should be an encrypted text.

Second

> Cannot find type [TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
>   ArgumentList]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded

Are all the necessary powershell components install / available.

I would start by running the comands manually on one of the servers first to check that it works.

Comment: First: I'll double-check that it's not escaping the flag/param name. Your observation makes sense and is a good place to start.

Second: I logged into the server through the built-in account that you make when you provision them and ran the commands manually. Everything works without issue when I run this manually.

Comment: It was something very close to the first issue you mentioned with escaping.The root-cause of the issue didn't occur to me until I noticed that even though I have been editing this inside the editor within the azure portal, and the script error it returned no longer matched. It was transforming/re-encoding several hyphens **(-)** as '**Æ€**"' so i was consistently getting weird line-ending errors everywhere in the places I had made edits. I learned about it after i went to the download location of the powershell script at `C:\Packages\` , opened it up and saw the mal-encoding in my file.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at setting up Azure AD Directory Services (Azure AD DS) to support this hybrid setup that will allow you to join Azure based VMs to your AD forest.

Take a look at this tutorial:  [Tutorial: Join a Windows Server virtual machine to a managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm)